# Grab rows and then cells from a table

Tags: php, html, simple-html-dom

I'm using the [Simple HTML Dom Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm) to grab a table (in the image) and then grab each `tr`. This outputs all the items in the row as one string.

```
$contents = $html->find('div[class=product-table]', 0);
$titles = $contents->find('tr');
```

[image]

How can I create an array that keeps the data in rows but also allows me to output the individual cells? I want to be able to say there's 7 cells in a row (this could be flexible) and be able to output each individual cell in the row as variables (I need to do other stuff with these).

---

```
// Product Code Titles
$contents = $html->find('div[class=product-table]', 0);
$data = array();
$rows = $contents->find('tr');
$counter = 1;
foreach ($rows as $key_row => $row) {
    // process rows here
    foreach ($row->find('td') as $key_cell => $cell) {
      $field_key = "field_5ae0882f9d6f9";
      $data[] = array(
        "column_title" => strip_tags($cell->innertext),
      );
      $counter++;

        // process each cell on the current row iteration
        // or whatever you need to do in each cell (calculations and whatnot)
        // $data[] = then push it inside an array (you can prolly use the keys and use it in `$data`)
    }
} ?>
<pre>
<?php print_r($data); ?>
</pre>
<?php update_field( $field_key, $data, $post_id );
```

Comment: just loop on each row first, then you can decide if you want to further loop each cell (first foreach level the rows, second foreach the cells)

Comment: @Ghost I guess it'd be nice to add it all to an array, with the initial array being the row then inside that each cell.

Comment: yeah you could do that, in essence, you could treat it as a multi leveled array, (you have the table as the parent array ) each row represents each sub level, and then inside each row they have key pair values. `Array ( Array ( size => 3, weight => 99 kg ... and so on ) )`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just like what I've said in the comments, treat the first loop for the rows, and for each row, another foreach for each cell. So basically you need two.

There's not much to go on since you don't have a sample markup, but here's the idea:

```
$data = array();
$rows = $contents->find('tr');
foreach ($rows as $key_row => $row) {
    // process rows here
    foreach ($row->find('td') as $key_cell => $cell) {
        // process each cell on the current row iteration
        echo $cell->innertext;
        // or whatever you need to do in each cell (calculations and whatnot)
        // $data[] = then push it inside an array (you can prolly use the keys and use it in `$data`)
    }
}
```

Sidenote: Take note, if you want the header to be skipped, just use a counter and an if condition with continue, then you're good to go.

Comment: Thanks got it working, all very clear. Onto the next problem - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51039679/updating-acf-parent-and-child-repeaters

Comment: @Rob i got to see the next question, not really well versed on wp and with acf but are you sure you're getting the correct field id for the parent, and shouldn't you be putting the subfields after the the foreach loop cell is done?

Comment: Thanks for looking, very kind. I've got it to add rows to the sub repeater so it seems it's the correct field names etc. I've moved the `add_sub_row` outside the loop but it's now only adding 1 row whereas before it added 7 but didn't fill in the data.

Comment: I don't think you need to know WP or ACF necessarily, it's more just getting the logic correct.